# How to Exclude directory and its contents in gradle war

Tags: java, war, gradle

I am using `gradle` war plugin, I am trying to exclude some directories inside `WEB-INF` directory while packing a war, but the excludes don't seem to work.
This is what I have

```
 war {
   webInf {
        from 'src/main/config'
    }
   exclude('metadata/**')
  }
```

Any solution on this ?

Answer (score 3):

To **exclude** a folder named `metadata` contained in `WEB-INF` use the following code in your build.gradle file:

```
war.rootSpec.exclude("**/WEB-INF/metadata/")
```

or depending on your coding style you could also use:

```
war 
{ 
    rootSpec.exclude("**/WEB-INF/metadata/") 
}
```

[This link on the gradle discussion forum may also be of help](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-exlude-files-from-war-when-using-war-plugin-against-default-or-webappdirname-location/7366)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Exclude-properties-file-from-war-td3365147.html? If so only remember, that in recent versions of Gradle (I'm using 1.6) there's `sourceSets.main.output`.
It'd helpful if you could specify what metadata is and attach your project's layout.

One more thing: you may also like to:

```
//remove jars only for provided compile
classpath -= configurations.providedCompile
```

Answer (score 0):

[see this post and comments](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.gradle.user/7828)

```
war {
// remove classes from the classpath <<<<<<<
classpath = configurations.runtime

// add them in explicitly, with the filtering applied
webInf {
    into('classes') {
        from sourceSets.main.classes
        exclude 'org/gradle/sample/excludeme/**'
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        src {
            srcDir 'config'
            exclude 'metadata/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation how the approach solves the problem is always helpful.